# Always getting 403 Forbidden error even thought it should return 404 Not Exists (Java Spring application problem)

Tags: java, spring, http-status-code-403

I am having the problem with Java 17 Spring Maven application because it always returns to me 403 Forbidden status in Postman when I test my code. I locate the problem within securityFilterChain() method but I am not sure how could I fix this.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    private final JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthFilter;

    private final AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                        .requestMatchers("/api/v1/city/**").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/api/v1/auth/**").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .sessionManagement(sess -> sess.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        return http.build();
    }
}
```

Has anyone experienced similar problem.

Thanks in advance!

When I disabled:
`.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider) .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);`
and                        `.requestMatchers("/api/v1/city/**").permitAll() .requestMatchers("/api/v1/auth/**").permitAll()`
Then it gives right response but then i dissable JWT Authentication

[Example of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHeVZ.png)

[Example of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTKlL.png)

Comment: add a screenshot of the request u r sending in postman, this seems like authentication problem "wrong username or password, or wrong jwt".

Comment: It is not a problem with authentication. It is giving me the 403 Forbidden when i try to use the city API without token, and gives me the right JSON Response when I ask for right city. The problem is that when i look for imaginary city, it doesnt give me back JSON response with 404 Error, it gives me again 403 Forbidden

Comment: ok, include these info in the question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are being redirected to /error page which is secured by spring-security. so you should permit it

add

```
.requestMatchers("/error").permitAll()
```